# How do I fix "Kivy CalledProcessError: returned non-zero exit status 1"?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am attempting to build an app I built in kivy using buildozer. However, when I run the command "build osx debug", I get the following error:

```
    CalledProcessError: Command '['python', 'package_app.py', '/Users
    /ajax/Documents/.buildozer/osx/app', 
    '--appname=musicalapp', '--bundlename=Music Favorites', 
   '--bundleid=org.test', '--bundleversion=0.1', '--displayname=Music 
   Favorites']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thank you!

Here is the full log:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "package_app.py", line 234, in <module>
   main(arguments)
   File "package_app.py", line 217, in main
   bootstrap(source_app, appname, confirm)
  File "package_app.py", line 79, in bootstrap
  sh.cp('-a', source_app, appname)
  NameError: global name 'sh' is not defined
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 9, in <module>
  load_entry_point('buildozer==0.32', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildozer/scripts
  /client.py", line 13, in main
  Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py",    
  line 1020, in run_command
   self.target.run_commands(args)
   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets 
   /osx.py",     
  line 234, in run_commands func(args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets/osx.py",
  line 250, in cmd_debug
  self.buildozer.build()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line
  210, in build self.target.build_package()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets/osx.py",
  line 155, in build_package
  check_output(cmd, cwd=cwd)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib 
 /python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
 raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['python', 'package_app.py', 
 '/Users/ajax/Documents/.buildozer/osx/app',
 '--appname=musicalapp', '--bundlename=Music Favorites', 
  '--bundleid=my_app.test', '--bundleversion=1.0', 
  '--displayname=Music Favorites']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: Post the full log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although a bit of sloppy job, you can find your sh.py file somewhere in your site_packages folder and place it next to your package_app.py (i.e in the same directory) :)